# rerun trigger after record has been updated

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created the following trigger.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `SOS`.`auto_field`
BEFORE INSERT ON 
SOS.Tickets
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.DURATION = 0)THEN
SET NEW.DURATION = NULL;
END IF;
SET NEW.MONTH = SUBSTR(NEW.DAY, 1, 2);
SET NEW.JOUR = SUBSTR(NEW.DAY, 4, 2);
SET NEW.YEAR = SUBSTR(NEW.DAY, 7, 4);
IF (NEW.SEVERITY = 1)THEN
SET NEW.THRESHOLD = 240;
END IF;
IF (NEW.SEVERITY = 2)THEN
SET NEW.THRESHOLD = 480;
END IF;
IF (NEW.SEVERITY = 3)THEN
SET NEW.THRESHOLD = 10080;
END IF;
IF (NEW.SEVERITY = 4)THEN
SET NEW.THRESHOLD = 43200;
END IF;
SET NEW.WEEK = WEEK(STR_TO_DATE(NEW.DAY,'%m/%d/%Y'),1);
IF (NEW.DURATION > NEW.THRESHOLD)THEN
SET NEW.SLA_OUT = 'OUT';
END IF;
IF (NEW.DURATION != '')THEN
SET NEW.GLOBAL_HOUR_DURATION = NEW.DURATION/60;
END IF;
END
```

What i need, is for it to run again when i make a change to an old record, so that it updates with the correct values.

Comment: just add this as an BEFORE UPDATE trigger too.

Comment: 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `SOS`.`auto_field`
**BEFORE UPDATE ON** 
SOS.Tickets
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
.....'

That easy?

Comment: Why should it be more difficult? Give it a try!

Comment: ok, can i add it to the same trigger or do i need to create a 2nd one?

Comment: You could not add two events to the same trigger name, so you've got to create two triggers with different name, even if the contain the same body.